# Assign the random value based on satisfied condition accordingly to the matching index of pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, random

I am trying to populate data in python.

The code is below.

The intention of the code is to choose a random value in the range and populate the panda's variable according to the size of dataframe column .
To Achieve the solution I define index and item variable in the for loop
if the condition is met, then add the random value at the index of the looped variable in a new variable position

```
import scipy.stats as stats
for index , item in df['RangeCategory']:
    if (item ==  'RC1' ):
        upperLim = 0.5
        lowerLim = 50.4
        df["ItemFlagged"][index] =  random.uniform(upperLim, lowerLim)
    elif (item ==  'RC2' ):
        upperLim = 50
        lowerLim = 250.4
        df["ItemFlagged"][index] =  random.uniform(upperLim, lowerLim)
    elif (item ==  'RC3' ):
        upperLim = 250
        lowerLim = 300.4
        df["ItemFlagged"][index] =  random.uniform(upperLim, lowerLim)
    elif (item ==  'RC4' ):
        upperLim = 300
        lowerLim = 500.4
        df["ItemFlagged"][index] =  random.uniform(upperLim, lowerLim)
    elif (item ==  'RC5' ):
        upperLim = 500
        lowerLim = 900.4
        df["ItemFlagged"][index] =  random.uniform(upperLim, lowerLim)
    elif (item ==  'RC6' ):
        upperLim = 900
        lowerLim = 1500.4
        df["ItemFlagged"][index] =  random.uniform(upperLim, lowerLim)
    elif (item ==  'RC7' ):
        upperLim = 1500
        lowerLim = 3000.4
        df["ItemFlagged"][index] =  random.uniform(upperLim, lowerLim)
    elif (item ==  'RC8' ):
        upperLim = 3000
        lowerLim = 5000.4
        df["ItemFlagged"][index] =  random.uniform(upperLim, lowerLim)
    elif (item ==  'RC9' ):
        upperLim = 5001
        lowerLim = 9000.4
        df["ItemFlagged"][index] =  random.uniform(upperLim, lowerLim)
    elif (item ==  'RC10' ):
        upperLim = 9001
        lowerLim = 10000.4
        df["ItemFlagged"][index] =  random.uniform(upperLim, lowerLim)
    elif (item ==  'RC11' ):
        upperLim = 10001
        lowerLim = 30000
        df["ItemFlagged"][index] =  random.uniform(upperLim, lowerLim)
    elif (item ==  'RC12' ):
        upperLim = 31000
        lowerLim = 50000
        df["ItemFlagged"][index] =  random.uniform(upperLim, lowerLim)
```

Dataframe has 100K Data.
Current Problem:**"Too many values to unpack"**

I came across the issue **"Too many values to unpack"**. can you please guide me here on a correction?

Expected Result:
Assign the random value based on satisfied condition accordingly

Best Regards,
Gabe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use loc function to assign values:

```
for index , row in df.iterrows():
    if row['RangeCategory'] == 'RC1':
        upperLim = 0.5
        lowerLim = 50.4
        df.loc[index,"ItemFlagged"] = random.uniform(upperLim, lowerLim)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution,

```
import random

# define a look up RangeCategory
range_lookup = {"RC1": [0.5, 50.4], "RC2": [50, 250.4]...}

df['ItemFlagged'] = (
    df['RangeCategory'].apply(lambda x: random.uniform(*range_lookup[x]))
)
```